# Returning a non-standard format for Date in a JSON response from Rails using as_json on the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rails-activerecord

I'm attempting to reformat a date being returned by from the database (Date format) as a formatted string (format: %m%d%y) in order for it to be output by a separate client application.

Formatting it on the client side is not an option as only the web app is under our control.

```
def as_json(options={})
  super(
    :except => [:id, :created_at, :updated_at],
    :include => {
      :children => {
        :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
      }
    }
  ).merge(:tasks_total => self.tasks_total)
end
```

I've attempted to use a after_initialize callback, however that simply result in a nill value being passed to the client.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get around the issue of rails enforcing the data type on attributes in as_json, I used something like this instead, with a hash:

```
def as_json(options={})
  {
    name: name,
    date_of_birth: self.date_format(date_of_birth),
    more_info: more_info,
    children: children.map(&:as_json)
  }
end
```

The `date_format` call is because this model actually has multiple dates that need formatting in the same way.

Thanks to @rbates for the help.